# cert manager keeps using edit in place

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I have created some ingresses with edit in place true and with a temporary certificate, later on i remove the relevant annotations from the ingresses and when new certificates requests where automatically created for the renewal of the certificates from the cert manager, the manager kept editing the existing ingress instead of creating a new one for the renewal, i have not found any relevant information in the docs, does anyone have an idea how to force cert manager not to present the challenge in the existing ingress but instead create a new one, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the generated certificates had kept in an annotation the name of the ingress, so the renewal kept using the existing ingress instead of creating a new one, i had to delete the ingresses and then recreate them.